Suppose $Y\perp X\mid Z$, then does $I(Y<X)\perp I(Y > y_0) \mid Z$?
Let $X,Y,Z$ be arbitrary continuous random variables, and let $y_0$ be any constant belong to the support of $Y$.
Suppose $Y\perp X\mid Z$, I wonder if we have $I(Y<X)\perp I(Y > y_0) \mid Z$.
Here is my thought process: since $Y\perp X\mid Z$, $P(I(Y<X)=1\mid Z) = P(I(Y<X)=0\mid Z) = 1/2$. So conditioning on $Z$, the indicator random variable $I(Y<X)$ acts like a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $1/2$. Thus it is independent from the indicator random variable $I(Y > y_0)$ given $Z$, where the randomness comes from $Y$.
How about the reverse implication? Suppose $I(Y<X)\perp I(Y > y_0) \mid Z$, does $Y\perp X\mid Z$?
I want to show $f_{Y\mid X,Z}(y\mid x, z) \ne f_{Y\mid Z}(y\mid z)$. I understand that
$$f_{Y\mid X,Z}(y\mid x,z)=\frac{f_{Y,X\mid Z}(y,x\mid z)}{f_{X\mid Z}(x\mid z)},$$ is there any way to leverage the assumption $I(Y<X)\perp I(Y > y_0) \mid Z$?

The two indicator r.v-s are not independent. We have $P(I(X<Y), I(Y<a)) = P(I(Y<a)) P(I(X<Y)| Y<a)$ which is clearly $\neq P(I(X<Y)) P(I(Y<a))$. To intuitively see this, consider $X$ and $Y$ uniform on $[0,1]$. Then if constant $a$ is close to zero, for example, it certainly affects $P(X<Y)$ (or $I(X<Y))$ -- the two r.v-s are dependent. Same if you add conditioning on Z.
